# classNotFound error by maven?

Tags: java, import, maven-2, noclassdeffounderror, maven-dependency

I am learning maven but I am facing problem in importing dependencies, following is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myapp.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>myapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
       <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Following is my java file

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
    }
}
```

I compiled using **mvn compile** and created jar using **mvn package** both executed without any error. but when I run application using command

```
java -cp target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.myapp.app.App
```

it showing following errors

```
Hello World!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient
        at com.myapp.app.App.main(App.java:16)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: That means Maven didn't bring that JAR down for your project OR it's not packaged properly.  Start with the latter.

Comment: do you have errors while packaging?

Answer (score 4):

Reason why it gives `noclassfound` error is that, when you package it , it doesn't creates a **fat/uber** jar and jar file in which `FTPClient` is present, that is not part of your `myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` , hence you get **noclassfounderror**.

**Maven Assembly Plugin** helps you to create a fat jar(includes the dependency) jar and creates a runnable jar, where you give your FQCN of `Main` method. Hence when you run the fat jar it will have all the dependencies and your program will run fine.

Include below plugin in your pom.xml and run `mvn package` command.

```
<!-- Maven Assembly Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                    <archive>
                      <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.myapp.app.App</mainClass>
                      </manifest>
                    </archive>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                                        <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Note :- here change the **mainclass** with fully qualified class name of yours.

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve problem adding some code to `pom.xml` here is the code I added

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>dependency/</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>com.example.MainClass</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <useBaseVersion>false</useBaseVersion>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

After compiling and running the project it runs perfectly.

When I am using `mvn compile` it is just compiling my Main Class but it's not combining dependencies. That's why when I am trying to run JAR file it's giving error `ClassNotFound`, for this you need to add `mvn plugin copy-dependencies` and add execution tag to execute mvn command `copy-dependencies`

Comment: you shoud understand why your are adding a particular peice of code and what was the reason behind the error. i explained that it in my answer , please give it a try and let me know.